# Where can I find more information about Urdvaergs?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, campaign-settings, dwarf

This Web article on [Dwarves](http://midgardsaga.mine.nu/dwarves.php) mentions the Urdvaergs:

> Extremely rare to be seen, an Urdvaerg is almost regarded as a half-god by other dwarves. It is said they live for thousands of years and that they master every fighting technique possible, as well as the powers of the runes and smithy. They are even told to be able to see the near future. Those few that are allowed to become an Urdvaerg's disciple are destined for great deeds that will change the course of the world. An Urdvaerg prefers to live alone and is seldom seen in any of the dwarf keeps.
>   The three greatest lords of all dwarves, Dvalinn, Durinn and Motsognir are Urdvaergs.

Is more information about this race's statistics, special abilities, and background available elsewhere for D&D 3.5e? If no further information is available, what statistics and special abilities would be appropriate?

---

***Note:*** I have also posted this question on the Steve Jackson Games forums [here](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?p=2112007),  the Giant in the Playground forums [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?528548-Dwarf-urdvaerg-abilities), the enworld forums [here](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?561173-DWARF-URDVAERG-ABILITIES), and on reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/6jmg70/weekly_questions_thread_111/dji36sj/).

Comment: I'm starting to think this is asking about a homebrew port of [this defunct student project video game](https://www.facebook.com/Midgard-Saga-529291173805858/) to a ttrpg.

Comment: itf for either d&d 3.5 or 4th or 5th edition d&d norse midgard settingg campaign

Comment: Please pick one system. The site *can* accommodate this question as currently posed, but the site *can't* accommodate this question if the question's modified to encompass three wildly different editions. Further, it may be useful to include what, exactly, the urdvaergs will be used for in the campaign: will they be NPC antagonists or are they to be suitable for use as a PCs?

Answer (score 1):

The Urdvaerg appears to exist only in Midgard Saga, a custom server for Neverwinter Nights 2. There is no information on them in D&D beyond the quote posted.

A [half-celestial](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/halfCelestial.htm) dwarf, perhaps with levels in [dwarf paragon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/races/racialParagonClasses.htm), would fit all of the narrative requirements:

- "Extremely rare to be seen": Half-celestial is an uncommon and non-standard race.
- "Regarded as a half-god": The half-celestial is literally half divine. According to the SRD, "half-celestials are always comely and delightful to the senses".
- "Live for thousands of years": Aasimar in AD&D live longer than humans, so it's likely that the more powerful half-celestial would live longer than a standard dwarf, who is already long-lived.
- "Master every fighting technique possible": Dwarf paragons also have proficiency with all weapons, armor and shields.
- "Master ... the powers of the runes": Half-celestials gain spell-like abilities as they increase in level. Their Int/Wis/Cha bonuses mean that half-celestials make excellent spellcasters of any class.
- "Master ... smithy": Dwarves are innately good at smithing, and dwarf paragons gain a bonus to smithing.
- "Told to be able to see the near future": Half-celestials have +4 to Wisdom, while dwarf paragons have a bonus to saving throws. You could further modify this by giving them Foresight instead of Summon Monster IX.

Comment: (It's useful to explain in answers to questions like this the extent of the research performed to reach a decisive *No.* That way readers understand that the answerer's done more than hit the *Google* and say *Nope, guess not!* and posted the answer. (For instance, if such info exists, this answer could include more information about that custom server and the events thereon that led to the creation of the Urdvaerg.) Following that *No* with *Here's one way to homebrew a solution based on available info* is, by the way, legit… but the question comes first. Thanks for the effort today, BTW.)

Comment: The first part (which actually answers the question) is good, the second... you *could* use half-celestials as a base, maybe, but the fit is not nearly as good as you imply. Half-celestials are not really divine, there are nothing explicitly stating they live longer, mere proficiency with many weapons is far from mastery of all weapons *and techniques*, “the powers of the runes” isn’t really a thing in the system, and merely having high Wisdom is not remotely the same as seeing in the future.